# Excel - VLOOKUP or COUNTIF to count Matches from 2 Columns?

Tags: excel, count

I'm trying to get a count of matches from two columns. Let's say I have a table with the following data.

Cars

```
In column A I have colours of cars e.g. Red, Yellow, Black, Green
In column B I have the type of car e.g. Diesel, Automatic, Manual
```

I want a count of all red cards that run on diesel so which function would I use?

```
Column A has 3 red cars
Column B has 6 diesel cars in total but only 1 of the red cars is a diesel.
```

I've tried :

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A10,"Red")+COUNTIF(B2:B10,"Diesel")
```

But it gives a combined count of all red cars and all diesel cars (9), not all red diesel cars, which should be 1.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `=COUNTIFS()` formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A10,"Red",B1:B10,"Diesel")
```

Answer (score 0):

You choud do an operation for each row, and sum all.

[image: Formulas]